# display unet predicted image using cv2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

I have trained a model using images and masks, and predicted one single image.
The shape of the images im predicting is `(1024,1024,3)`

Code.

```
nueva_imagen = cv2.imread("../input/dataset/Training_dataset/Images/all_imgs/zanzibar_4_35_04.jpg")
print(nueva_imagen.shape)
nueva_imagen = cv2.resize(nueva_imagen,(256,256))
nueva_imagen = np.expand_dims(nueva_imagen,axis=0)
print(nueva_imagen.shape)
pred_img = model.predict(nueva_imagen)
print(pred_img.shape)
#pred_img = np.squeeze(pred_img,axis=0)
#print(pred_img.shape)
```

The reason why I add another dimension its because my model only takes images with 3 dimension.
At the end my predicted image shape is `(1,256,256,1)`
Now reading cv2 docs i cant show images with 4 dimension so here is what i have done.

```
image_to_predict = _images[789]
mask_of_image = masks_arr[789]



pred_img = np.squeeze(pred_img,axis=0)
pred_img = np.squeeze(pred_img,axis=2)



fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=0.4)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1);plt.title("original image")
ax.imshow(image_to_predict)

#ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2);plt.title("mask")
#ax.imshow(mask_of_image)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2);plt.title("Predicted image")
ax.imshow(pred_img)
```

i removed dimensions on axis 0 and 3 to show the image but what i get its a purple image.
Is that the predicted image or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Some checks you might want to perform (hard to tell without acces to the model & images):

- When you load the image with OpenCV, images are stored as BGR and not RGB. If you trained your model on images loaded with OpenCV, this should not be an issue. But if you use the `fit` method on a directory, you might want to convert from BGR to RGB with `cv2.cvtColor(nueva_imagen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`
- Make sure that the image preprocessing is the same between your training and predictions. Typically, check that both of them have values either in [0, 1] (as float) or [0, 255] (as int)
- Same goes when using Matplotlib regarding the [0, 1] values

Comment: I trained my model with images loadead/proccesed with keras `ImageDataGenerator`. Checking my proccesed images vales goes [0,255] but my predict image goes [0,1]

Comment: Then you might want to transform your image to predict to [0, 255] and to RGB: `(cv2.cvtColor(nueva_imagen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) * 255).astype('uint8')`